# Deploying Xamarin.Forms app to iOS: MT1006 EOF Error (error: 0xe800000e)

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am trying to run a Xamarin.Forms app on my iPad and getting the following error:

`Launch failed. The app 'AppIOS' could not be launched on 'My iPad'. Error: error MT1006: Could not install the application '/Users/mycompany/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/AppIOS/someguid/bin/iPhone/Debug/my.app' on the device 'My iPad': EOF Error (error: 0xe800000e).. Please check the logs for more details.`

This app has previously ran fine on the same device.  The iOS build and deployment process seems very unstable so it often takes multiple attempts so I'm used to having to restart Visual Studio, the Mac it builds on and the iPad and generally wasting a whole lot of time.  I have restarted everything involved here multiple times but this error persists.  I have checked the device logs and there are no related messages or even any messages at the appropriate times.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.4), Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK (12.2.1.12), building on a Mac Mini running macOS Mojave and XCode 10.1, deploying to an iPad Air (A1474) running iOS 12.1.1.  As far as I'm aware there have been no updates to any of these since I last had it working.  The UWP version of the app runs fine.

I can find a lot of MT1006 issues but none with EOF Error (error: 0xe800000e) and I can find no information about this specific error at all.  Can anyone enlighten me on what this means?

Comment: Did you try to delete the application from the iPad as well?

Comment: go to /Users/mycompany/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/ path on MAC system and remove your project and run it again. hope it helps

Comment: Did you recently install a Xamarin.iOS update?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds overly simple, but I just had this issue and I solved it by restarting the iOS device and redeploying it.  Specifically, I was deploying to an `iPod 6th Gen` and I held the `power` and `home` buttons until the screen turned black, this is more of a hard restart.  Then let the device reboot and try deploying again.

NOTE: Don't hold the `power` and `home` buttons too long, because if you do, the iPod will go into a factory reset restart.

Answer (score 3):

Try pulling up the device in Xcodes' devices tab. I did and realized the device had an error within the tab. I then disabled the "Connect via network" button, then things started to work properly.

Comment: Indeed, first thing to try if having deployment errors. In my case the device was busy caching files from the iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

I am agree, Xamarin build environment on iOS part is very buggy.
In any case of unknown error in such config: VS<->MAC<->iOS Device try these steps:

1. Try to switch Off and On Mac wifi.
2. Reconnect VS to Macbook and Macbook to IPhone.
3. Delete bin and obj folders on Macbook
4. Check your PList and Entitlements file(as example wrong aps-environment setting can cause installing errors)
5. Check your sign project settings
   5a. Check your provisoning profile term
6. unistall application from ios
7. rebuild and run project again

I'll appent new lines in case i'll remember something else.
What you described happened to me and solved by 1,2,7

Comment: Switching the wifi off and on did the job, thanks